# How to code data selected and not selected in r

Tags: r

I have two datasets. One is the big original one (lets call this x). The other data set is the subsetted dataset from the original x (lets call this y). I want to add a column in the x data set that determines whether the participant was selected or not. How do I do that?

thank you.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show the expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to tell exaclty without looking at data, but see if this example explains the approach:

```
> x <- data.frame(ID = 1:10,
+                  Name = LETTERS[1:10],
+                  Score = round(rnorm(10, 50,2)))
> x
   ID Name Score
1   1    A    49
2   2    B    52
3   3    C    49
4   4    D    52
5   5    E    48
6   6    F    47
7   7    G    56
8   8    H    49
9   9    I    51
10 10    J    51
> y <- subset(x, ID > 6)
> y
   ID Name Score
7   7    G    56
8   8    H    49
9   9    I    51
10 10    J    51
> x$In_y <- ifelse(x$ID %in% y$ID, 1, 0)
> x
   ID Name Score In_y
1   1    A    49    0
2   2    B    52    0
3   3    C    49    0
4   4    D    52    0
5   5    E    48    0
6   6    F    47    0
7   7    G    56    1
8   8    H    49    1
9   9    I    51    1
10 10    J    51    1
>
```